# Help to identify this solo recording setup

Tags: microphone, mixing, setup

Looking at [this video from youtube](http://youtu.be/56AKl4uHKjA?hd=1) featuring the amazing Bob McChensey playing the trombone, I can identify two microphones, the Royer R-121 and the old Sony C-37A. I can see both mics in use, would you guys have any idea how they would be mixed and why they have used both?

Comment: wow thanks, I did not know about this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for using microphones of different types is generally to get the best features of both. Key would be:

- The Sony, a condenser mic, has a sound which is often considered brittle and sharp, but very good for vocals
- Ribbon mics usually have a more broadly balanced output, so aren't as peaky in a particular frequency range
- The sound pickup gives a slightly different spread as well, with the condenser mic being a bit more directional

In terms of mixing they would both be EQ'ed individually to get the sound the producer wants - this is very subjective, but with two differing microphones you just get more parameters to play with to bring out the sound you want in that venue.

Also have a read of [this question on microphone differences.](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/4854/674)